# How to serialize an object as a single value in Gson?

Tags: java, class, gson

When you have a class to be converted to a json, if it contains a BigDecimal attribute, it will return a json like this:

```
 Response {
       BigDecimal price;
 }
 //json:
 {
     price: 20.20
 }
```

Note that BigDecimal is a class. Its behavior is like an primitive (integer, float).

I want to produce the same behavior (a class return a single information to json)

Example:

```
class Response {
    Money value
}

Money {
    BigDecimal price;
}

//What is returning:
{
    value : { price: 20.20 }
}

//What I want:
{
    value : 20.20
}
```

Comment: Try to register a BigDecimal type adapter to a GSON builder.

Comment: I will try to improve the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Gson` doesn't have such a feature out of the box. You'll need to implement it yourself.

If it's just for the `Response` type, you can simply implement your own `TypeAdapter`.

```
class ResponseTypeAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Response> {
    @Override
    public void write(JsonWriter out, Response value) throws IOException {
        out.beginObject();
        out.name("value");
        // check for null, if applicable, and use a default value, or don't write anything at all
        out.value(value.getValue().getPrice());
        out.endObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Response read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
        // implement the deserialization
    }
}
```

Then register it.

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(Response.class, new ResponseTypeAdapter()).create();
// test it
String json = gson.toJson(new Response(new Money(new BigDecimal("20.20"))));
```

This would now serialize to

```
{"value":20.20}
```

---

If you can use Jackson, it comes with a [`@JsonValue`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) annotation which does this for you. For example,

```
class Money {
    private final BigDecimal price;
    public Money(BigDecimal bigDecimal) {
        this.price = bigDecimal;
    }
    @JsonValue // <<< this
    public BigDecimal getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

used with

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(new Response(new Money(new BigDecimal("20.20"))));
```

will generate

```
{"value":20.20}
```

The [javadoc](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonValue.html) states

> Marker annotation similar to `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlValue` **that
>   indicates that results of the annotated "getter" method (which means
>   signature must be that of getters; non-void return type, no args) is
>   to be used as the single value to serialize for the instance**. Usually
>   value will be of a simple scalar type (`String` or `Number`), but it can
>   be any serializable type (`Collection`, `Map` or Bean).
>
> At most one method of a Class can be annotated with this annotation;
>   if more than one is found, an exception may be thrown. Also, if method
>   signature is not compatible with Getters, an exception may be thrown
>   (whether exception is thrown or not is an implementation detail (due
>   to filtering during introspection, some annotations may be skipped)
>   and applications should not rely on specific behavior).